# Query available disk space by xquery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

How can I query available disk space on a given location by xquery?

e.g. something like `xdmp:filesystem-info($path as xs:string)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't find it for any location, but you can find it for individual forests using elements from `xdmp:forest-status`.  You can use the `data-dir` and `device-space` elements to find the space on the device associated with the data directory.

Comment: Monitoring history also records these values over time (forest device-space), you can query the Meters database for historic values.